# Angular not parsing json

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a static json file that I'm trying to access through $http service. The static resource is located at data/user/person.json. The $http service sends out a request and gets back the expected result with content-type:application/json and statuscode:200.

On angular's side however, the code enters the 'catch' callback, instead of success with the following error:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.
```

The ' refers to the first character in response after the curly braces. If I change 'name' to just name I would get SyntaxError:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n.
```

Why is angular having diffuculty parsing this json response?

The json response and relevant code is below:

```
{'name':'johndoe', 'age':99}

function getUser() {
    $http({url: 'data/user/person.json', method: 'GET'}).success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
        console.log('status:' + status);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        //this block is entered
        console.log(err);
    });
};
```

This is the full printout of the error message:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token n
at Object.parse (native)
at Yb (http://localhost:8000/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:14:208)
at $d.e.defaults.transformResponse (http://localhost:8000/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:67:366)
at http://localhost:8000/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:67:127
at Array.forEach (native)
at r (http://localhost:8000/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:7:280)
at wc (http://localhost:8000/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:67:109)
at c (http://localhost:8000/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:68:297)
at I (http://localhost:8000/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:97:187)
at http://localhost:8000/Scripts/angular/angular.min.js:98:350
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For json to be **[valid json](http://jsonlint.com/)** your data structure should be like

`{"name":"johndoe", "age":99}`

Double Quotes, and around your keys too.